# Как при повороте Activity сохранить данные в диалоге AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, activity

Подскажите пожалуйста как при повороте Activity сохранить данные в диалоге AlertDialog.Builder

Есть Activity в ней код

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View v1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_car, null);
        alert.setView(v1);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.show();
```

На слое  R.layout.dialog_edit_car расположены  EditText, RadioButton
Вопрос: как сохранить их данные при поворотое activity. Метода onSaveInstanceState и onRestoreInstanceState у AlertDialog.Builder не нашел. Как правильно поступить?

Comment: Попробуйте переделать в DialogFragment - там весь нужный функционал есть

Answer (score 3):

Сделал так

```
public class MainActivitySettings extends AppCompatActivity {
View viewSettingsDialog = null;  //наш алерт диалог

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}

@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if(viewSettingsDialog!=null) {
            ((EditText) viewSettingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText_driveMarka)).setText(savedInstanceState.get("key").toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if(viewSettingsDialog!=null) {
            outState.putString("key", ((EditText) viewSettingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText_driveMarka)).getText().toString());
        }
    }

protected void addCar(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        viewSettingsDialog = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_car, null);
        alert.setView(viewSettingsDialog);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.show();

        ((Button) viewSettingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveSettings)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```